# Salto de línea y sin comillas fputcsv

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

Tengo un pequeño problema con exportar a CSV desde PHP, concretamente con fputcsv.

Tengo éste código:

```
$valor1='1';
$valor2='2';
$valor3='3';

$campo = "campo1, campo2, campo3";
$valor = "$valor1, $valor2, $valor3";

$list = array (
        array($campo),
        array($valor)
        );

$fp = fopen($rutacsv, 'w'); //va a la ruta escogida en $rutacsv. OK //

        foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

Éste funciona pero en el csv se lee así:

```
"campo1, campo2, campo3" "1, 2, 3"
```

Y yo quiero que salga así:

```
campo1, campo2, campo3
1, 2, 3
```

Es decir, lo busco sin comillas y con salto de línea.

**¿Es posible?**

Gracias!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estas creando un arreglo de 2 columnas.

Al hacer:

```
$valor1='1';
$valor2='2';
$valor3='3';

$campo = "campo1, campo2, campo3"; //String
$valor = "$valor1, $valor2, $valor3"; // String
```

Estas creado strings sin más

Lo que deberias hacer es crear un elemento en el arreglo para cada valor, algo asi:

```
<?php
$valor1='1';
$valor2='2';
$valor3='3';

$campo = array("campo1", "campo2", "campo3"); 
$valor = array($valor1, $valor2, $valor3);

$lista = array ($campo, $valor);

$fp = fopen('fichero.csv', 'w');

foreach ($lista as $campos) {
  fputcsv($fp, $campos);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Bien, me funcionó pero sin saltos de línea. Gracias!

Comment: Que version de PHP estas usando?

Comment: La versión de PHP es la 7.2.7 (la que viene en el último XAMPP).

Comment: Parece que el problema estaba en el Notepad (default). Con otro editor más avanzado si que me lo saca OK.

Comment: Ok, estaba revisando la documentacion oficial y en versiones anteriores de PHP habia un bug, pero en tu caso usas php 7 ahi esta corregido. Si te sirvio la respuesta no olvides marcarla como solución a tu problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que convertir las cadenas en arrays asi:

```
$valor1='1';
$valor2='2';
$valor3='3';

$campo = array("campo1", "campo2", "campo3");
$valor = array($valor1, $valor2, $valor3);

$list = array (
        $campo,
        $valor
);

$fp = fopen($rutacsv, 'w'); //va a la ruta escogida en $rutacsv. OK //

foreach ($list as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Chequea este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080456/fputcsv-and-newline-codes

Comment: Lo miro, ya lo tengo cerca ;) Gracias, a ver que puedo conseguir.